# easy way to restore incremental rsync backup?

Tags: rsync, backup-restoration, incremental-backup

I have incremental rsync backups of a folder, created with:

```
rsync --delete -a -v --backup --backup-dir="../backup_`date +%Y-%m-%d`" /orig /backups/dest
```

so I have a copy of current `/orig` on `/backups/dest` and modified files on `/backups/backup_YYYY_MM_DD/`

my question is there's any easy way to restore the backup as it was **on specific date**?

Answer (score 2):

As the various backup dirs only contain the changed files by the last current backup, the restore procedure is somewhat complex: you need to restore the current full backup and re-apply the various file-level backup, up to the required (past) date.

Can I suggest you a better backup method? Please use the `--link-dest` option combined with proper rotation.

Even better, give a look at [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org) and [its doc](http://rsnapshot.org/rsnapshot/docs/docbook/rest.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
rsync -a --delete /backups/backup_YYYY__MM__DD/orig/ /orig/
```

should suffice.

Take care of the trailing slash at the end of the source directory pathname.

HTH

Comment: `/backups/backup_YYYY_MM_DD/orig` only contains the modified files since last backup

Comment: Oh I see. I made some more testing. I'm afraid you've got to re-apply all of the backups you made up the desired backup. Something along the lines : `rsync -a  ..../backup_n /orig` then `rsync -a  ..../backup_n-1 /orig`, ... You'd have been better using rsnapshot, probably.

Comment: I already had thought about restoring each backup folder, but rsync will not delete newly added files, so I could get a restored folder with files that were not at the original one. You are right, would be easier to restore an rsnapshot backup

Comment: finally did a `rsync` for each backup until date, then erased newer files with `find -mtime`

Comment: I'm afraid that doing so you also delete files that have just been modified after the "good" backup instead of reverting them to their previous "good" state.

Comment: I don't think so, since every change made after desired restoration date has its previous state backed up, and rsync preserves modification time